# PM2 cron jobs list view

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2

Good afternoon,

I started two cron jobs with pm2 and was wondering if there was a way to list the cron jobs.
Both of my cron jobs execute a shell script to start/stop a server.

Note: Also, is there a log of the cron jobs? Would I have to configure my own shell script to log it in a text file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. I can't understand the question.

```
pm2 status
```

is not enough for you?

2. You can see log without other configuration by

```
pm2 log "job name"
```

It gives last 15 line of stdout and stderr.

If you want to see more logs, stdout is in ~/.pm2/log/"job name"-out.log
and stderr is in  ~/.pm2/log/"job name"-error.log

FYI) If log file is too big, uses pm2 logrotate

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-logrotate